# Do the constructors of React Components need the props argument?

Tags: reactjs

Should I include the props argument in the constructor and call to super if I am not using props at all for a component?

For example, if I write:

```
class NotePage extends React.Component<void, State> {
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {
            filterStr: "string"
        };
    }
    ...
}
```

Will this cause any issues?

I'm asking because if I include props then flow complains about a missing annotation and one way to solve the problem is to remove the props argument.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From official docs [`React Constructor`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#constructor)

> you should call super(props) before any other statement. Otherwise, this.props will be undefined in the constructor, which can lead to bugs

```
constructor(props) {

  // no super call
}
```

If you don't call it, the data passed from parent as properties is not available inside child component's constructor with `props`. Props will, however, still be available in the rest of the component, such as the render function.

e.g.

```
class Parent extends React.Component{

    render(){

        return (<Child  mydata = {'some data here'}/>)
    }
}

class Child extends React.Component{

   constructor(){
    super(); //no props
    this.props.mydata //will be undefined
   }

  render(){
    this.props.mydata //defined
  }
}
```

Comment: its not like that, check this fiddle and you will get to know https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/98272/

Comment: @stack26..but in fiddle it displaying value not underfined....even we are not passing props in constructor or super either?

Answer (score 4):

First of all you don't need constructor function at all, when you are not accessing props in initialization of component. You can write your state this way:

```
class NotePage extends React.Component<void, State> {
   state = {
      filterStr: "string"
   }
    ...
}
```

Only when you are using props for initialization you need to , make use of constructor and call this way:

```
class NotePage extends React.Component<void, State> {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            filterStr: "string"
        };
    }
    ...
}
```

Hope this helps !!

I found a great link written by @dan Abramov (react core team). this also might help people understanding super(props). [Link](https://overreacted.io/why-do-we-write-super-props/)